# combine all elements of one list to each element of another list -- simple javascript problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a list of cities in HTML. I have a list of things to do in HTML. When a button is clicked, I want to create a combined list where each city has a child list that contains the list of all the things to do.

See the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/benschnell/zjq3cr52/70/).

Currently the list of things to do only displays as a child of the last city instead of each of them. What am I doing wrong?

After the button click, I want the output to be as follows:

```
<div id="combined">
  <ul id="cityList">
    <li>
      <h3>New York</h3>
      <ul class="thingsToDoList">
        <li class="todo">Restaurants</li>
        <li class="todo">Theatres</li>
        <li class="todo">Museums</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Seattle</h3>
      <ul class="thingsToDoList">
        <li class="todo">Restaurants</li>
        <li class="todo">Theatres</li>
        <li class="todo">Museums</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
      <ul class="thingsToDoList">
        <li class="todo">Restaurants</li>
        <li class="todo">Theatres</li>
        <li class="todo">Museums</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Atlanta</h3>
      <ul class="thingsToDoList">
        <li class="todo">Restaurants</li>
        <li class="todo">Theatres</li>
        <li class="todo">Museums</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But currently the output looks like this:

```
<div id="combined">
  <ul id="cityList">
    <li>
      <h3>New York</h3>
      <ul class="thingsToDoList"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Seattle</h3>
      <ul class="thingsToDoList"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
      <ul class="thingsToDoList"></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Atlanta</h3>
      <ul class="thingsToDoList">
        <li class="todo">Restaurants</li>
        <li class="todo">Theatres</li>
        <li class="todo">Museums</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my current HTML

```
<div id="cities">
  <ul>
    <li class="city">New York</li>
    <li class="city">Seattle</li>
    <li class="city">Los Angeles</li>
    <li class="city">Atlanta</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="thingsToDo">
  <ul>
    <li class="todo">Restaurants</li>
    <li class="todo">Theatres</li>
    <li class="todo">Museums</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="combine">Combine</button>

<div id="combined">
  <ul id="cityList">
  </ul>
</div>
```

And my current JS

```
const cities = document.getElementById('cities');
const thingsToDo = document.getElementById('thingsToDo');
const combine = document.getElementById('combine');
const combined = document.getElementById('combined');
const cityList = document.getElementById('cityList');

combine.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 
  let allCities = document.querySelectorAll('li.city');
  
  [].forEach.call(allCities, function(city){
    let eachCity = document.createElement('li');
    let cityHeader = document.createElement('h3');
    cityHeader.innerText = city.innerText;
    cityList.appendChild(eachCity);
    
    let thingsToDoList = document.createElement('ul');
    thingsToDoList.setAttribute('class', 'thingsToDoList');
    eachCity.appendChild(cityHeader);
    eachCity.appendChild(thingsToDoList);
  }); // close allCities loop
  
  let newThingsList = document.querySelectorAll('.thingsToDoList');
  [].forEach.call(newThingsList, function(tList){
    let allThingsToDo = document.querySelectorAll('li.todo');
    [].forEach.call(allThingsToDo, function(thing){
      tList.appendChild(thing);
    }) 
  })        
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is you are appending the same node over and over and it ends up on the last one? (rather than creating a new node or cloning the node) You can use .cloneNode(true) on your selector to actually clone the node. I put together a shorter example that does this. Not sure if it meets all the requirements, but hopefully it's helpful.

Note: this example, like yours will keep adding more if you keep clicking the button. Logic would need to be added to prevent this if that what you wanted.

```js
const cities = document.getElementById('cities');
const thingsToDo = document.getElementById('thingsToDo');
const combine = document.getElementById('combine');
const combined = document.getElementById('combined');
const cityList = document.getElementById('cityList');

combine.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 
  let allCities = document.querySelectorAll('li.city');
  
 allCities.forEach(element => {
   let cityLi = document.createElement('li');
   let cityHeader = document.createElement('h3');
   cityHeader.innerText = element.innerText
   cityList.appendChild(cityHeader);
   cityList.appendChild(cityLi);
   cityList.appendChild(thingsToDo.cloneNode(true));
 });
 });
```

```html
<div id="cities">
  <ul>
    <li class="city">New York</li>
    <li class="city">Seattle</li>
    <li class="city">Los Angeles</li>
    <li class="city">Atlanta</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="thingsToDo">
  <ul>
    <li class="todo">Restaurants</li>
    <li class="todo">Theatres</li>
    <li class="todo">Museums</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="combine">Combine</button>

<div id="combined">
  <ul id="cityList">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!